# Problem with parsing results from a nested object

Tags: node.js

I have an object with the following structure, let's say the object name is `apiCall`:

```
{ 
   "Status":"OK",
   "ID":"xxx",
   "Results":[  ]
}
```

And this is the structure of the Results array:

```
[ 
   { 
      "Call":{ 
         "ID":1,
         "CustomerKey":null,
         "CustomerID":null
      },
      "PingID":4,
      "Key":null,
      "Properties":[ 
         { 
            "Name":"OrdinalID",
            "Value":"1"
         }
      ],
      "CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000",
      "ID":0,
      "ObjectID":null
   }
]
```

Everything works perfectly fine and I am able to retrieve everything except the nested `Properties`.

So this is how I retrieve for example Call.ID when iterating through Results - this works fine:

```
apiCall.Results[i].Call.ID
```

Now when I try to get the `Properties` nothing works - I tried parsing, stringifying, and also the following:

```
apiCall.Results[i].Properties.Value;
apiCall.Results[i].Properties.OrdinalID;
Stringify(apiCall.Results[i].Properties.Value);
```

nothing from above works.

This is the only thing that somehow worked so far:

```
Stringify(apiCall.Results[i].Properties);
```

and it's giving the following result:

```
[{"Name":"OrdinalID","Value":"1"}]
```

How can I get to the actual value?
Thank you

Comment: you need to access your object the following way: `apiCall.Results[i].Properties[0].Value`

Comment: Cause here `Properties` is an Array you treat that as like Object. So we have to mention the index of that array like - `apiCall.Results[i].Properties[0].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Properties` property is an array, so you need to include an index similar to what you did with `Results[i]`.

Like so: `apiCall.Results[i].Properties[0].Value` (using `0` as the index here).